# Syncing QfField with Android

Tags: qfield, android, ios, qgis-cloud

I've been running into syncing errors when trying to view new files I've uploaded to my desktop QGIS project (synced with QField Cloud project) on my Android device. I'm unable to view files and a search of the GIS forums indicates that other Android users have run into similar issues with QField. Are IOS users also encountering problems syncing with QField Cloud?